# Sims 3: Aging options are greyed out

Tags: the-sims-3, windows-8.1

The question says it all. I went in to set all my options after a fresh install of The Sims 3, and everything seems to be editable except the aging options. All of those are greyed out.

This seems like something that SOMEbody would had had issues with before, but I can't find anything anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an EA Community Manager on the help [forums](http://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-3/Can-t-change-aging-options-in-sims-3/td-p/317808):

> You have to start a new game or load one of your saves to be able to change the aging options. They can be set differently for each saved game.